# Database giving value twice

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get value from multiple columns from multiple tables. The code looks like this:

```
<?php

$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","en","]9");

mysql_select_db("en");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT title, field_id_1 FROM exp_channel_titles, exp_channel_data") or die(mysql_error());

// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // looping through all results
    // products node
    $response["video_path"] = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       // temp user array
        $s1 = explode('"',$row['field_id_1']);
        $path = array();
        $path["field_id_1"] = $s1[5];
       $path["title"] = $row["title"];
        array_push($response["video_path"], $path);
    }
    // success
    $response["success"] = 1;
     // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // no products found
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No products found";

    // echo no users JSON
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

In the result the values are appearing twice instead of only once. I checked the two tables, but these two tables do contain the column of the same name.

Comment: Now change your password.

Comment: Do you need access to the server? I changed the password and database name before posting.

Comment: Good - just checking ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Did You run query from Your code in mysql client?

You are making implicit cross join, that's why you are getting what seems to be duplicated result. In fact You are getting cartesian product of both tables.

Read more about this at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join and consider using left join.

Since You didn't publish schema of your tables I can't tell you more.

Answer (score 0):

Cehck output of query

SELECT title, field_id_1 FROM exp_channel_titles, exp_channel_data

Join two table based on relations, use distinct, This will solve your problem

Comment: Could you please type the query of it. don't know the complex query like that.\